# jQuery UI modal progress bar

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a file in php that downloads a file and extracts it contents. I now execute that file periodically by creating a batch file and assigning it to the scheduler. How will i be able to popup a progress bar that shows the status of the task file like downloading, extracting and so on.... I need to show the progress bar only when the task executes, say @ 6 pm daily...

like this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/loadingbox/load1.JPG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code for adding a description-text to the progressbar (if you need)

```
  <style>
      .ui-progressbar-text{
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
        top:-17px;
        text-align:center;
      }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar()
      .append('<div class="ui-progressbar-text" ></div>');
  </script>
```

the script wo request the text-file ever 200ms:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  $.get('currenttask.txt', function(data) {
    $('#progressbar')
      .progressbar({value: data.split(";")[0]}) //update the progressbar-value
      .find('.ui.progressbar-text') //update the progressbar-description
        .html(data.split(";")[1])
        .end()
      ;
  });
},200);
```

the text-file:

```
--begin of file
"30;extracting"
--end of file
```

the php-script creates the text-file with one line who contains a value and a text who represent the current executing task.

Comment: what is 'current.txt' and will the text file be created automatically.

Comment: the text-file must you create in your php-file

Comment: Oh. i understood. pls check: while executing the batch file, i must include a file to which i write the current phase of the process. Then i use setInterval () and get() to fetch the data from this file and use it to update the progress bar...

Comment: @Floyd: Hey man. U r a genius. I was never bothered abt ur english. U cud give me what no one else could not. I just needed the logic, i needed to understand it. and coz f u i was able to understand. The problem with me is that i try to put other's logic in my own terms so that i can understand it. that's y i asked u for a clarification, also, i am new to such concepts. Forgive me if u taught that i had trouble with ur english. Once again thanks...

Comment: @Floyd: also because of u i came to know abt js.fiddle.net... u r gr8 man

Answer (score 2):

You set the progress of the progress bar yourself with `.progressbar( "value" , [value] )` function.

You will need to work out the percentage loaded of the current process for this to work. For example, you may want to show the progressbar to pre-laod all your images.

```
// Define all image locations.
var source = ["apple.jpg", "orange.jpg", "pear.jpg", "banana.jpg"];
// Store HTML image objects in an array.
var imgObj = [];
// Store count of fully loaded images.
var imagesLoaded = 0;

for(var i in source) {
    // Create each image object, assign load function and 'src' attribute.
    imgObj[i] = new Image();
    imgObj.onload = function(e) { imageLoaded(e, source.length);
    imgObj.src = source[i];
}

function imageLoaded(e, loadTotal) {
    // Calculate percent of images loaded, send value to jquery UI element.
    imagesLoaded++;
    $('#myProgressBar').progressbar("value", 100 * (imagesLoaded / loadTotal));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a modal with a spinner gif inside it, when the task is completed it informs the user and close.

If you want something more complex as a true progress bar (percentage) jQuery UI has a progress bar widget where you can set progress by mean of

```
.progressbar({ value: x });
```

Comment: At first you can make a JSON-JavaScript-File with all tasks and PopUp-Times, descriptions... With setInterval you can execute an function periodly wo request the JSON-File per Ajax ("$.getJSON({url: ...})") interate the elements and check if the time is passed and popup / set the progressbar (what ever you want).

Comment: What does you mean with "how do i update the progress in another page with the progress of this task" ? if this "other page" is opend with window.open you can do: "var t = window.open("tasks.html",..); t.SetProgress("title","value",..);" in this case "SetProgress" is a function in "tasks.html" you can call from the parrent page.

Comment: Oh ok i understand. This is not realy posible with JavaScript but its posible ;).
Your batch-File creates JSON-Files at any directory who the can request by the webserver.
Like "{task: "extracting"}". With setInterval you request this file all 200ms and check for changes.
Now you update your progressbar.

Comment: Like: window.setInterval(function(){
  $.getJSON('ajax/currenttask.json', function(data) {
    $('#progressbar')
      .progressbar({value: data.value})
      .find('.ui.progressbar-text)
      .html(data.taskDescription);
  });
},200);

Comment: use a text-file instead of json: window.setInterval(function(){
  $.get('ajax/currenttask.txt', function(data) {
    $('#progressbar')
      .progressbar({value: data.split(";")[0]})
      .find('.ui.progressbar-text)
      .html(data.split(";")[1]);
  });
},200);

the Text-File-Content: "30;extracting"

Comment: Ok .. i have sey that you are download and extracting with a batchfile. your batchfile create now a text-file befor each step.

#-- start of batch --
echo "0;downloading" >> c:/inetpup/wwwroot/tasks/currenttask.txt
#the download code

echo "30;extracting files" >> c:/inetpup/wwwroot/tasks/currenttask.txt
#the code for this step

echo "60;one step more" >> c:/inetpup/wwwroot/tasks/currenttask.txt
#the code for this step

echo "100;complete" >> c:/inetpup/wwwroot/tasks/currenttask.txt
#-- end of batch --

this text-file "currenttask.txt" can the code i post above, request and parsing.

Comment: wtf -- why i can't post code-blocks in comments like: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6407/allow-html-tags-in-comments

Comment: what does the battch-file doing?

Comment: @Floyd: it contains php file link.... php file to be executed. - "file1" and i use this batch file to execute "file1"...file 1 contains code for downloading a file and extracting its contents....

Comment: ok i understand. the new way: your php-file create the text-file and put this in any from web reachable directory. this file contains the value for the procressbar and the text. now the setInterval-Script from above check every 200ms if the file has changed and update your proggressbar.

Comment: oh.. understood.. So could u format ur previous setInterval script in an understandable form..

Comment: i have post it as an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265106/jquey-ui-modal-progress-bar/4266108#4266108